# Is there a shorthand to match e.g. "anything of int"

Tags: ocaml

Say I have a variant like:

```ml
type myvar = A of int | B of int
```

I can write a function like:

```ml
let myvar_to_int = function
| A i -> i
| B i -> i
```

Let's say I have lots more elements in the variant, all `<something> of int` ...

Is there any shorthand for writing the to_int function? e.g. a way to express `<anything> of int` in a match case?

(In other places in the code I want to be able to distinguish my `A`s from `B`s and match on them explicitly still)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If every variant has an int then you really have a pair of distinct values:

```
type ab = A | B
type myvar = ab * int

let myvar_to_int = snd
```

Otherwise, no there's no way to do what you want. You can write slightly more compactly:

```
let myvar_to_int = function
| A i | B i -> i
```